# Avoiding use of SELECT in WHERE

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an input file on hdfs in CSV format with following cols: `date, time, public_ip`

Using this I need to filter out data from quite a big table (~100M rows daily). The table has the following structure (roughly):

```sql
    CREATE TABLE big_table (
        `user_id` int, 
        `ip` string, 
        `timestamp_from` timestamp, 
        `timestamp_to` timestamp) 
    PARTITIONED BY (`PARTITION_DATE` string)
    ROW FORMAT SERDE
        'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
    STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
        'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat';
```

I need to read CSV data and then filter `big_table` checking which user_ids have been using the desired ip address in selected period.

I tried using spark SQL with different joins, without much luck. Whatever I do, spark is simply not "smart" enough to limit big table per partition. I also tried using `WHERE PARTITION_DATE IN (SELECT DISTINCT date FROM csv_file`, but this was also quite slow.

CSV should have up to 20 different days or so.
Here's my solution - I ended up picking up distinct days and using this as a string:

```scala
    spark.sql("select date from csv_file group by date").createOrReplaceTempView("csv_file_uniq_date")
    val partitions=spark.sql("select * from csv_file_uniq_date").collect.mkString(sep=",").replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","")
    spark.sql("select user_id, timestamp_from, timestamp_to from big_table where partition_date in (" + partitions + ") group by user_id, timestamp_from, timestamp_to").write.csv("output.csv")
```

Now, this does the work - I cut the tasks from 100s of thousands to thousands, but I feel quite unhappy with the implementation. Could someone point me to the right direction? How to avoid pulling this as a string of comma separated partition values?

Using spark 2.2

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you expect is called `Dynamic Partition Pruning`, by which Spark will be smart enough to resolve the partitions to filter from the direct join condition.

This feature is available from `Spark 3.0` as part of Adaptive Query Execution improvements.

Find more details from this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/dynamic-partition-pruning-in-spark-30)

It is disabled by default, can be enabled by setting  `spark.sql.adaptive.enabled=true`

Comment: As for as I know, your approach is better with Spark 2.2.* version. From 3.0 version, this will be auto resolved. Please upvote if the answer has helped you.

Comment: ok, this is depressing :(. thank you for your help, though.